# How to read a file line by line

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

**I try to read a file line by line.**

File to read:

```
polkit|0.105
NetworkManager|0.9.4.0
GConf|3.2.5
libgnome-keyring|3.4.1
mozilla-nss|3.13.5
network-manager-applet|0.9.4.1
...
```

Script:

```
COUNTER=1
until [ $COUNTER == '$(sed $= -n /tmp/packages-install)' ]; do
    FIRST[$COUNTER]=$(head -n $COUNTER /tmp/packages-install | cut -d\| -f 1)
    version[$COUNTER]=$(head -n $COUNTER /tmp/packages-install | cut -d\| -f 2)
    echo "${FIRST[$COUNTER]}"
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done

echo "${FIRST[2]}"

MYARRAY=()

for ((i=1; i < ${#FIRST[@]} ; i++)); do
    MYARRAY=( ${MYARRAY[@]} ${FIRST[$i]} ${version[$i]} )
done

Xdialog --menubox Choose 20 100 1 "${MYARRAY[@]}"
```

When I execute the script, this window will be opened:
(Notice how some values are repeated, and the contents don't correctly alternate between names and versions):
[image: Xdialog window]

**I'd like to create an array with all package names and versions.**

Comment: That code is quite a lot of flavors of wrong. Read BashFAQ #1 on how to correctly read from a file: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: ...also, failing to quote your expansions means that anything with a space (or an expandable glob) is going to mess you up very, very badly. Run all this code through http://shellcheck.net/ for a detailed list of issues with explanations.

Comment: BTW, part of what's messing you up is that `head -n 3` doesn't give you the third line, it gives you the *first three lines*, so you get the lines at the top of your file repeated over and over.

Comment: Thank you for the link. There I can check my files. :)

Comment: I've tried to edit this to be readable by a wider array of English speakers. It still conflates a number of issues together rather than asking about only one well-isolated problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- a program that needs XDialog and a file installed in `/tmp` to run isn't as self-contained as it should be), but probably no longer qualifies as unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a counter for this at all, and invoking `head` twice for every single line is insanely inefficient.

```
array=( )
while IFS='|' read -r name version; do
  echo "Package $name is at version $version" >&2
  array+=( "$name" "$version" )
done </tmp/packages-install
```

See [BashFAQ #001: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Can I also save the $name in the array?

Comment: @linuscl, this already does save both the name and the version in the array.

Comment: I'd like to save only the $name in the array.

Comment: ...you might also consider using an associative array: `declare -A versions; while IFS='|' read -r name version; do versions[$name]=$version; done` -- then you can iterate over names with `"${!versions[@]}"` or retrieve the version for any given name with `"${versions[$name]}"`.